# Get Options from Models post on Html Django

Tags: python, html, django

I'm having some issues trying to get the list out of the model and print it dynamically on my HTML view.
Here's what I've done so far, and what I've got as view.

models.py

```
class Projeto(models.Model):

    acoes = (
        ('', "---------"),
        ('Projeto', "Projeto"),
        ('Evento', "Evento"),
        ('Curso', "Curso"),
    )

    areas = (
        ('', "---------"),
        ('Comunicação', 'Comunicação'),
        ('Cultura', 'Cultura'),
        ('Direitos Humanos e Justiça','Direitos Humanos e Justiça'),
        ('Educação', 'Educação'),
        ('Meio Ambiente', 'Meio Ambiente'),
        ('Saúde', 'Saúde'),
        ('Tecnologia e Produção', 'Tecnologia e Produção'),
        ('Trabalho', 'Trabalho'),
    )
```

views.py

```
def lista_projetos(request):
projetos_unemat = Projeto.objects.order_by('id')
page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
paginator = Paginator(projetos_unemat, 10)

try:
    users = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    users = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    users = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

lista_acoes = Projeto.acoes
lista_areas = Projeto.areas

context = {
    'projetos': users,
    'acoes': lista_acoes,
    'areas': lista_areas
}

return render(request, 'lista_projetos.html', context)
```

_filter.html

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <select class="form-control col-4" id="acoes">
    {% for acao in acoes %}
       <option name="{{acao}}"> {{acao}} </option>
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary fas fa-search" type="submit"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my page shows this:
[page view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsGSW.jpg)

How do I get to show only the options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to access the individual properties of the tuple in your template. Replace this:

```
{% for acao in acoes %}
   <option name="{{acao}}"> {{acao}} </option>
{% endfor %}
```

with

```
{% for acao in acoes %}
   <option name="{{acao.0}}"> {{acao.1}} </option>
{% endfor %}
```

(You likely want to use the `value` attribute as well, but you don't explain your use-case.)

Comment: It worked perfectly. I need to make a filtering using the value selected.
I'll put my filter here so you can see.